# How to work around I/O bottleneck when writing to multiple files using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, file-io

I currently have a multi-threaded program that crawls websites and writes their text to a file.  CPU wise I could have tons of threads running at once but quickly the I/O becomes a bottleneck.  I was thinking I could have each thread write to a Array Blocking Queue, but I know I am going to generate more than my available 32GB of ram.  Is there a way to have the Array dumped to a text file after it reaches a certain size so that I can free up that space?  Or is there another way around this I/O issue I am missing?

Comment: Couldn't you just a use collection and serialize it?  Then you just swap objects you're writing to.

Comment: I would make a single thread, which is your gatekeeper to the array. Access array with some function. If array reaches certain size, kick off worker thread which writes out part of array to disk. Just use one thread, b/c your file will be linear (if you keep it simple) and the disk will likely be your bottleneck, not the CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an image there is SATA 2 controller which allows to write with 300 MB per second speed. Now it is a question what is the Internet connection bandwidth of our imaginary computer. I know that the last maximum bandwidth in production which is supported by Ethernet adapters is 1 GB per second. But I think such bandwidth of Internet connection is very expensive (I even doubt that some commercial hosts support it). I think that 300 MB per second Internet connection is enough. Let our computer has such one.

Result is

```
      Input (300 MB/s);

      Writing (300 MB/s).
```

Resume: If you want to download Internet, you must increase connections and disks as well as disk controllers. Otherwise 300 MB/s looks pretty nice. And threads don't help you. CPU and memory doesn't relate to our problem either.

Answer (score 1):

I would not have a "ton" of threads running. I would profile with varying numbers of threads on a particular system until I found the number of reader threads that provided the maximum throughput. I suspect this number would be pretty small. Basically, you just want enough to keep the CPU busy while waiting for other server responses.

I'd have one writer thread for each physical drive that you are writing to. Connect the reading threads to the writer thread with a `BlockingQueue` with a finite size; if the readers get too far ahead of the disk, this will throttle their activity.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's disk I/O that is the bottleneck because of thrashing around so many files, yes?  Can you write whole files at once - crawl the site, add buffers to a buffer-collection, then queue the buffer-collection to one file-writing thread?  That sequential writing would improve disk performance, yes?   If buffering whole sites is not feasible, then you could collect enough buffer instances per site to make a disk write worth while, (I dunno, when the total collected exceeds 64K say), before queueing the collection off the the writer thread and starting to collect a new set of buffers.

The easy way to improve multi-file write latency - get an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Use fewer threads! They aren't buying you much. The entire problem is network-bound at one end and disk-bound at the other. Not much CPU involved at all really.